# CakePHP saving with out conventions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a relationship set up on a model with a primaryKey set to 'Document.guid' along with this i have an associated model DocumentVersion.

```
class Document extends DocumentAppModel {

public $hasMany = array(    
    'DocumentVersion' => array(
        'className' => 'DocumentVersion',
        'foreignKey'  => false,
        'finderQuery' => 'SELECT * FROM document_versions as `DocumentVersion` WHERE `DocumentVersion`.`document_guid` = {$__cakeID__$} ORDER BY `DocumentVersion`.`version` DESC LIMIT 1'
     )
);
```

}

```
class DocumentVersion extends DocumentAppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
       'Document' 
    );
}
```

When i try and use a $this->Document->saveAll() it only saves the Document data and not the associated data. From my understanding it has something to do with the fact i am not using cakephp conventions to make my association.

My data structure

```
            $filtered[] = array(
                'Document' => array(
                    'guid' => $upload['guid'],
                    'database_revision' => Configure::read('Settings.LocalDataBaseRevision')
                ), 
                'DocumentVersion' => array(
                     array(
                        //'guid' => $upload['guid'],
                        'parent_guid' => (isset($upload['parent_guid'])) ? $upload['parent_guid'] : null,
                        'document_type_id' => $upload['type'],
                        'owner' => $upload['owner_id'],
                        'editor_id' => (isset($uplaod['editor_id'])) ? $uplaod['editor_id'] : null,
                        'title' => $upload['title'],
                        'crc' => (isset($upload['crc'])) ? $upload['crc'] : null,
                        'payload' => (isset($upload['payload'])) ? $upload['payload'] : null,
                        'database_revision' => Configure::read('Settings.LocalDataBaseRevision'),
                        'version' => 1 // Always set version number to 1 on uploads
                     )
                )
            );
```

Comment: Which is data that you want to save?

Comment: I have edited my question so you can see the format of my data

Comment: To troubleshoot, change Document hasMany Document_revision to a standard relation (i.e., no `finderquery`). If that `saveall` works, then you know its because of the `finderquery` option. Otherwise, it is your array format. If it is because of the `finderquery`, I recommend you have 1 hasMany relation for all document relations (which you can use for saving) and 1 hasOne relation for the most recent version.

Comment: Tried that and still no difference unfortunately. I am convinced that it's to do with something to do with changing my primaryKey in the Document model.

Comment: I changed my hasMany on DocumentVersion to a string rather then an array and the associated on SaveAll works fine, however this creates a new problem with me because i still need to return the newest version of DocumentVersion rather then a list of documents associated.

Comment: If you are using a different primaryKey, then you should tell it explicitly to cake model, like this `public $primaryKey = 'guid';` on your Document model, or any model that doen's use `id` as primary key

Comment: And why are you setting your `'foreignKey'` to false in your hasMany relationship?

Comment: finderQuery defines the foreignKey

Answer (score 0):

1. I forgot the prefix the plugin name on the model relationship.

   ```
   public $hasMany = array(
       'Document.DocumentVersion' => array(
          'className' => 'DocumentVersion',
          'foreignKey'  => false,
          'finderQuery' => 'SELECT * FROM document_versions as `DocumentVersion` WHERE `DocumentVersion`.`document_guid` = {$__cakeID__$} ORDER BY `DocumentVersion`.`version` DESC LIMIT 1'
        ));
   ```
2. I was still getting the same issue at this point however i finally resolved the issue by using deep association in my save method.

   $this->Document->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));